# Unknown host using ifconfig on system() call

Tags: c, linux, networking

I got a menu on C that creates a alias from a interface, when this call inside of the C program:

```
ifconfig eth0:0 192.168.xx.xx broadcast 192.168.xx.255 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```

I got:

> 192.168.xx.xx Unknown host

When I run that line on terminal, everything is fine.

Anyone got this problem?

**EDIT** Here is, a code that reproduces the problem.
When run system() with a const char* of that string it runs the command smoothly.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  char* test = (char*)malloc(128);

  char interface[20] = { "eth0:0" };
  char ip[20] = { "192.168.64.35" };
  char broadcast[20] = { "192.168.64.255" };
  char netmask[20] = { "255.255.255.0" };

  strcpy(test,"ifconfig ");
  strcat(test,interface);
  strcat(test," ");
  strcat(test,ip);
  strcat(test," broadcast");
  strcat(test,broadcast);
  strcat(test," netmask ");
  strcat(test,netmask);
  strcat(test," up");

  printf("%s\n",test);
  system(test);
  free(test);
}
```

**FIXED**

Here is what i've done to fix.
- Changed static references to dynamic references.
- Changed strcat use for sprintf.
- Avoid call a direct command ( hardcoded ) and used a script to interface it.

strcat and sprintf gave me a undefined behavior with system call with that use of variables with system call, the values printed seems to be correct, but something in system call seems to break the call. With dynamic use of variables that error is supressed. If anyone has a better explanation, please leave a comment. 
Thanks for support.

Comment: You need to show the code so we can see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @Barmar, the code is simply a system(that_string) , the system call that calls that line got this problem. When running "that_string" on terminal it creates the alias network just fine D:

Comment: There must be something different or it would work. So post your code.

Comment: If the string is created dynamically, show the code that creates it.

Comment: *the code is simply a system(that_string)...*  If you don't know what's wrong to the point of having to ask your question, you can't say what's correct.

Comment: The code exhibiting the problem is *not* "simply a system(that_string)".  Such a single function call is not a complete program; it can do nothing by itself.  But if a complete program that does nothing but execute such a line of code in fact reproduces the issue, then that would serve as a good basis for a [mre].

Comment: Okay, i created a example that recreate the problem.

Comment: Ah, i forgot to mention, the System that runs that code is a Debian 7.11

Comment: Debian 7 is end-of-life. Don't use it.
Also: `ifconfig` is deprecated on Linux and is superseded by the `iproute2` package. Don't use `ifconfig`, use `ip` instead.

Comment: Your code will leave no space between `broadcast` and its argument (`192.168.64.255`). Generally all that strcat'ing is error prone, dangerous and ridiculous. Have a look at `snprintf()`.

Comment: @Cheatah i can't is a solution already deployed for years, cant change it now.

Comment: @mosvy used snprintf too, but the error persisted.

Comment: Change `strcat(test," broadcast")` to be `strcat(test," broadcast ")`.